# Sliding two DIVs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need two DIV layers with height & width:100% each and when I click on DIV1 it has to `Slide from left to right` to load DIV2 and when clicked on DIV2 it has to `Slide from right to left` to load DIV1. I coded in the following manner which is working but sometimes DIVs are not being overlapped and two DIV slides one on top and other on bottom.

```
$("#div2").width("0");
$("#div1").click(function () {
    $("#div1").animate({ width: 0 }, "slow");
    $("#div2").animate({ width: "100%" }, "slow");
});
$("#div2").click(function () {
    $("#div2").animate({ width: 0 }, "slow");
    $("#div1").animate({ width: "100%" }, "slow");
});
```

Can anybody help me in coding something of this kind with better code than mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
$(function() {
    var $right = $("#right").width(0);

    $("#slide").click(function() {
        $("#left").animate({ width: 0 });
        $right.animate({ width: "100%" });
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/GFJXu/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div2").width("0");

$("#div1").click(myToggle('div1', 'div2'));

$("#div2").click(myToggle('div2', 'div1'));

function myToggle(open, close) {
   $("#"+close).animate({ width: 0 }, "slow");
   $("#"+open).animate({ width: "100%" }, "slow");
}
```